# Show $|\angle cod|=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: vectors

The four points $a$, $c$, $b$ and $d$ are collinear (lie on line $l$) and in that sequence.

The origin $o$ is some point not on the line $l$.

Given: $\vec{ac}=2\vec{cb}$, $\ \vec{ad}=2\vec{bd}\ $ and $\ |\vec{a}|=2|\vec{b}|$

Using scalar product or otherwise show $\angle{cod}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

[**Hint:** ($2\vec{a}+\vec{b})(\vec{a}-\vec{b})=2|\vec{a}|^2-2\vec{a}.\vec{b}+\vec{a}.\vec{b}-|\vec{b}|^2$]

**My solution:**

I first let, $\vec{a}=a_1\vec{i}+a_2\vec{j}$ and $\vec{b}=b_1\vec{i}+b_2\vec{j}$

I then found both $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$ in terms of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

Then by carrying out the operation $\vec{a}.\vec{b}$, I found that $\vec{a}.\vec{b}=0$ hence proving that $\angle{cod}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\color{blue}{\text{My question is:}}$

what is the meaning of the hint? I can't see how that fits in. It's probably exactly what I did or something obvious but I just can't see it.

Comment: I think they want to say that after expanding the two brackets. You get  $(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})(\vec{a}-\vec{b})=2\vec{a}^2-2\vec{a}.\vec{b}+\vec{a}.\vec{b}-\vec{b}^2$ which is equal to $2|\vec{a}|^2-2\vec{a}.\vec{b}+\vec{a}.\vec{b}-|\vec{b}|^2$ as $ \vec{a}^2=|\vec{a}|^2$ and $ \vec{b}^2=|\vec{b}|^2$

Comment: Also question title is misleading, but I guess your question would be too long to explain in the title.

Comment: But where does $(2\vec{a}+\vec{b})(\vec{a}-\vec{b})$ come from? That's what I can't see.